# What program manages the Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: desktop-environments

When I right-click on my desktop, sometimes there is a dark-grey menu with options "Change Background...", "Display Settings", and "Settings", and sometimes (not now), it's more normally-themed menu with "New Folder", "Paste", ... "Open Terminal". Clearly, I have two programs fighting it out for control of my desktop, and I should investigate uninstalling one of them, but what are their names? In Ubuntu 18.04 (and also 19.04, for that matter), what are the names of the mainstream-ish programs for rendering the desktop and its icons?

I've been using Ubuntu for several years now, but I don't upgrade with every LTS release and certainly not every minor release, and keeping track of all the architectural changes Canonical likes to make is exhausting.

Note that this is not exactly the same question as "what desktop environments do I have to choose from", but I assume it's closely related to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your right-click result looks like this formatting? [image]

It's [GNOME desktop](https://lifehacker.com/a-beginners-guide-to-the-gnome-desktop-1820890109), the default for 18.04 and 19.04.

Comment: That was one of the two contestants, yes. I don't suppose you know which the other one would be?